# Sqlalchemy can't connect to a mysql server

Tags: mysql, sqlalchemy

My legacy mysql 4.0.20 server is on a windows machine.
I'm developing a new system (python based) on a linux that needs to connect to the legacy server and make queries etc.
I have successfully connected using both plain MySQLdb and django. I'm having trouble connecting using sqlalchemy. Here is the code:

```
conn_str = "mysql://user:pass@192.168.171.233/dbd"
engine = create_engine(conn_str, echo=True)
metadata = MetaData(engine)
connection = engine.connect()
```

and the error stack I'm getting:

> 2011-03-01 08:35:04,613 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine.0x...b42c SELECT DATABASE()
>   2011-03-01 08:35:04,613 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine.0x...b42c ()
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> connection = engine.connect()
>     File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1811, in connect
>       return self.Connection(self, **kwargs)
>     File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 832, in **init**
>       self.**connection = connection or engine.raw_connection()
>     File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1874, in raw_connection
>       return self.pool.unique_connection()
>     File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/pool.py", line 142, in unique_connection
>       return _ConnectionFairy(self).checkout()
>     File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/pool.py", line 369, in __init**
>       rec = self._connection_record = pool.get()
>     File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/pool.py", line 213, in get
>       return self.do_get()
>     File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/pool.py", line 732, in do_get
>       con = self.create_connection()
>     File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/pool.py", line 147, in create_connection
>       return _ConnectionRecord(self)
>     File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/pool.py", line 258, in **init**
>       l.first_connect(self.connection, self)
>     File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/strategies.py", line 151, in first_connect
>       dialect.initialize(c)
>     File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/dialects/mysql/base.py", line 1753, in initialize
>       default.DefaultDialect.initialize(self, connection)
>     File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 159, in initialize
>       self.returns_unicode_strings = self._check_unicode_returns(connection)
>     File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 205, in _check_unicode_returns
>       unicode_for_varchar = check_unicode(sqltypes.VARCHAR(60))
>     File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 195, in check_unicode
>       ]).compile(dialect=self)
>     File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/MySQL_python-1.2.3c1-py2.6-linux-i686.egg/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 173, in execute
>       self.errorhandler(self, exc, value)
>     File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/MySQL_python-1.2.3c1-py2.6-linux-i686.egg/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 36, in defaulterrorhandler
>       raise errorclass, errorvalue
>   ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax.  Check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(60)) AS anon_1' at line 1")

Answer (score 1):

Looks like MySQL is reporting a syntax error in one of your SQL statements:

<snip>

```
1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax.
Check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server
version for the right syntax to use near
'(60)) AS anon_1' at line 1
```

</snip>

It looks like MySQL is objecting to a statement that includes the string:

```
(60)) AS anon_1
```

NOTE: I am not familiar with Sqlalchemy, but it looks to me like the exception (the SQL error from the statement) is getting propagated up to the handler specified in the connection.

FOLLOWUP:  It's likely that a query that Sqlalchemy is executing is not compatible with the older version of MySQL.  Looks like it's in the "_check_unicode_returns" function.

Have you tried disabling unicode support?

```
conn_str = "mysql://user:pass@192.168.171.233/dbd?use_unicode=0"
```

Comment: Thanks, but what is causing this error? I think it must be something specific to sqlalchemy, because MySQLdb connects fine by itself. Is it related to an old mysql version? My search on the web point to some CAST() function prior to this '(60)) AS anon_1'?

Comment: Given you've gotten the syntax error, that means sqlalchemy DID successfully connect, but as part of the connection process, some query (possibly retrieving DB info or user whatever) did fail, so the whole connection process is listed as failing.

Comment: I tried
    conn_str = "mysql://user:pass@192.168.171.233/dbd?use_unicode=0"
did not work